# Surjectiveness of $e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$ be given by $f(x)=e^{(x^2)}$. I am not sure whether this function is surjective or not.

If I am not wrong, I can see surjectivity for codomain $[1,\infty)$.
Let $y \in [1,\infty)$ then $\sqrt{\ln y} \in \mathbb R^+$. Say $\sqrt{\ln y}=x$. $\Rightarrow \ln y=x^2 \Rightarrow e^{(x^2)}=y=f(x)$. Could you please fix me if I made mistake?

However, I am not sure about $y<1$ case. I need help on this.

Very thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is not surjective, there does not exist $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1/2\in \mathbb{R}^+$ for example.

Comment: $x^2 \geq 0$ implies $e^{x^2} \geq e^0 = 1$, so, $\operatorname{im} f = [1,\infty)$

Comment: Don't be afraid to use modern tools:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4xmpeekp4x
Just remember this doesn't proof nothing, but you can get the idea from it.

Comment: It's surjective on $[0,\infty)$ but $\mathbb R^+ \ne [1,\infty)$.  If $y\in (0,1)$ then to have $e^{K} = y$ we must have $K = \ln y$ but as $y < 1$ then $\ln y < 0$.  So the have $e^{x^2} = y < 1$ we must have $x^2 = \ln y < 0$ and that.... is not possible for any $x\in \mathbb R$.  So the function can not be surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < y < 1$ then $\ln y< 0$.  So if $e^{x^2} = y< 1$ then $x^2  = \ln y < 0$.

Which... is not possible.

So $f(x) =e^{x^2} = y <1$ is not possible and $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: It should say "So if $e^{x^2} = y < 1$ then ..."

Comment: @amWhy why you rejected my correction?

Comment: @Leucippus Why you rejected my correction?

Comment: @jjagmath Your correction has been implemented.

Comment: I have no idea why they rejected your edit.  Perhaps they figure if I make a mistake, then correcting it borders on changing my intention and if I'm wrong I should hang by it than have an editor correct it for me?  Maybe.  Anyway you are right, it was a simple typo.

Comment: "Your correction has been implemented. "  No, it wasn't.  I, the author, saw it and corrected it myself.